# How to create a trigger on updating other table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, database-trigger

I want to create table name `birthrate` that relates to the main table `birth_t`, so when I insert data to `birth_t`, automatically `birthrate` table will also be updated.

`Birth_t` fields:

1. Birth_id
2. Name
3. Birthplace
4. Birthdate
5. Sex
6. Height
7. Weight
8. Mother
9. Father

`Birthrate` fields:

1. Id
2. Year (from `Birthdate` field)
3. Sum (summing birth rate from the year,  so we know how many babies that born in certain year)

How to create trigger for those?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the year from `Birthdate` and check it against the records in the other table to update the applicable record. This is how you can do it:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER birthrata_update BEFORE INSERT ON test1
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    insert into Birthrate(Year, Sum)
    select New.Year, 0
    from BirthRate
    where not exists (select 1 from BirthRate BR where BR.Year = New.Year limit 0, 1 );
    update Birthrate
    set Sum = Sum + 1
    where Birthrate.Year = YEAR(NEW.Birthdate);
  END;
|
```

This trigger should insert a row to `BirthRate` if it did not exist with an initial value of 0. And then it will increment the `Sum`.